# Apple/Xcode Git version update

Tags: security, git, xcode, macos-mojave

My employer uses a security scanning software to make sure we keep on top of what systems need software patches or security updates.

We've encountered an issue where the baked-in Apple version of Git is flagged as being out of date and vulnerable to a certain type of attack. This version appears to dwell in Xcode's Library and other support files. Installing Git separately either from the repository or through shell commands installs the correct up-to-date version in a separate location, meaning the vulnerable version is still flagged on reports.

Can I expect Apple to update Xcode/their version of Git from an Xcode update? A macOS update? Or will we be telling our software to override any of these flags for the foreseeable future.